# Should I use reportActivityStop or reportActivityStart when onPause() or onResume()

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics Tracker, data comes correctly to my analytics account. But I have a question. Should I do something when my app go to `onPause()` or `onResume()`

Currently I'm using this

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
}
```

### is something like below necessary?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
}
```

[image: Android activity life cycle]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but you don't need to call inside `onPause` and `onResume` as stated from the document.

> Note that this method should be called from the onStop() method in
>   each Activity
>
> This method should be called from the onStart() method in each
>   Activity

See [reportActivityStart](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html#reportActivityStart(android.app.Activity)) and [reportActivityStop](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html#reportActivityStop(android.app.Activity))

Also, if you want you can set the following value to automatically track activity(this won't track fragment). Note that this is for api 14 or above.

```
GoogleAnalytic.enableAutoActivityReports(true)
Tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true)
```